# Couldn't extend MapActivity

Tags: android, mapactivity

I am trying to extend MapActivity in my application. But each time I am getting an error. It says that to create a class named MapActivity. What to do? Please help.

Comment: there is no class named MapActivity in your project

Comment: Also there is no class named MapActivity in Android.

Comment: If you are using MapActivity, you need to build application in Google Api version.

Comment: Google API version building and minimum SDK 3.0

Comment: Follow this link to implement google map api version 2.

Comment: MapActivity is old stuff. Don't waste time there. Please start following Map API V2 at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably haven't done the steps required to set up a Maps project as described in Maps External API Overview. Read the following document, and you should be all set.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/